# SELinux allow http requests on Fedora 14

Tags: linux, security, java, fedora-14, selinux

I have a Fedora 14 instance on Amazon EC2 and I want to make an http request from that instance to another one in the same amazon security group. When I use wget to make the request it works fine. However, when I use Apache HTTP client running through JBoss 6 I get a

```
HttpClient ConnectException: Connection refused
```

JBoss does not run as root but rather as user "jboss". I suspect this is an SELinux issue. I logged in as root and I called

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

and

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_relay 1
```

But still no luck. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, double check that SELinux is, in fact, the culprit by checking your audit log in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.  There should be message with `type=AVC` related to JBoss.

Then, you can use that message in conjunction with the `audit2allow` tool to authorize the blocked access.  To authorize everything blocked for any binary with the name `jboss` in it thus far, run this as `root`:

```
grep jboss /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M jboss
semodule -i jboss.pp
```

However, it's better to only allow the specific permissions needed.  To do that, copy and paste the relevant lines from your audit log to a new file, and `cat` that to `audit2allow` instead.